# Snap: Handling multipart/form-data with mixed type input fields

Tags: haskell-snap-framework

I have a multipart data form with mixed type input fields. Something like this.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/files/upload">
  <input name="files" type="file" multiple />
  <input name="category" type="text" />
  <input name="description" type="text" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This should be pretty common as you'd want to supply some other data along with the actual file upload: group, description etc.

So since this is a multipart form data the usual "getPostParams" is out of the question.
If I handle it normal way with "handleMultipart", it does not even pick up the text fields.
Processing the above form with "handleMultipart" returns me a list with one part instead of three, which means it ignores the text input fields.

Any idea how to deal with it? How would I process the above form?

According to my research, if you mix fields in a multipart form you get an mime encoded message which should still contain all the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the form that is not a file should be put into [`rqParams`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.5.0/docs/Snap-Core.html#v%3arqParams)/[`rqPostParams`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.5.0/docs/Snap-Core.html#v%3arqPostParams).  If they are not there, then you should [submit a bug report](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-core/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open).  Try to be as detailed as possible.